# How to add Service to Finder Toolbar

Tags: finder

In the contextual menu (right click) on a folder or file object in the finder will give you the option to select "Services".  I wonder if there is some way to move those services into a button on the toolbar.  In particular I would like to add "New Terminal at Folder" to the toolbar.  Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: If you find the script corresponding to the service, you can just drag it onto the finder toolbar.

Comment: @alexis that is true, but for the life of me I cannot find it in the usual places (e.g. /System/Libarary/Services)

Answer (score 4):

You can create an application doing exactly this using ScriptEditor.app and then add it to Finder Toolbar.

First place this line inside your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
alias cdf="eval \"cd \\\"\\\`osascript -e 'tell app \\\\\\\"Finder\\\\\\\" to return the POSIX path of (target of window 1 as alias)'\\\`\\\"\""
```

This will change the active directory to the one of the topmost Finder window.

Then create an application in ScriptEditor.app like:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cdf"
    activate
end tell
```

Save this as an application and add it to the Toolbar with <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd> + Drag.

Comment: So first off, once in the tool bar, when clicked, all that happens os the script is opened in ScriptEditor.app instead of running the alias `cdf`.  When I try to run the alias at the terminal directly, I get `command not found`.  I suspect that the osascript command is not present.